# Statistics on ham operators age, internationally

Tags: europe, international-operating, japan, social

Are there statistics that cover more than the USA regarding how the age of

- licensed amateurs
- members of national ham organizations

is distributed? All I get are questionable sources on the internet for average ages, but I'd actually be interest in age cohort data, e.g. more a proper curve for ages 5 to 99.

I'm especially interested in numbers for

- Germany
- France
- Belgium
- Japan
- BRICS nations
- Commonwealth

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on your post, but if you want information on the UK (part of the Commonwealth), you can put a Freedom of Information Request through to Ofcom (The Office of Communications, the UK communications regulator).  Depending on whether they determine the information requested to be sensitive, they may provide statistics to you.  Just be precise in your question (and you don't have to be a resident of the UK

https://www.ofcom.org.uk/about-ofcom/foi-dp

Reference: [Information Commissioner's Office >> Who can make a freedom of information request?](https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/foi-eir-and-access-to-information/guide-to-freedom-of-information/what-is-the-foi-act/#:%7E:text=Anyone%20can%20make%20a%20freedom,campaign%20group%2C%20or%20a%20company.)

> Anyone can make a freedom of information request – they do not have to be UK citizens, or resident in the UK

Comment: I tried asking bard.google.com "Can you provide statistics, by age group, for all age groups, of licensed amateur radio operators in all countries of the world? I'd like the country, age group, percentage, count."  It came back with some good information, which it said came from https://www.iaru.org/